# System.InvalidOperationException while running RecognizeAsync

Tags: c#, voice-recognition, voice

I m creating win form app in `C#` which recognize the voice of user and then response it.When i try to say anything,this exception occur `An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Speech.dll`.

Please help if anyone know about it.
Here's my code for better understanding.....

```
  public partial class Form1 : Form
   {
    SpeechRecognitionEngine recEngine = new SpeechRecognitionEngine();
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void enableBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        recEngine.RecognizeAsync(RecognizeMode.Multiple);
        disableBtn.Enabled = true;
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Choices command = new Choices();
        command.Add(new String[] { "say hello" , "show my name"});
        GrammarBuilder gBuilder = new GrammarBuilder();
        gBuilder.Append(command);
        Grammar gram = new Grammar(gBuilder);
        recEngine.LoadGrammarAsync(gram);
        recEngine.SetInputToDefaultAudioDevice();
        recEngine.RecognizeAsync(RecognizeMode.Multiple);
        recEngine.SpeechRecognized += recEngine_SpeechRecognized;

    }

    void recEngine_SpeechRecognized(object sender, SpeechRecognizedEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (e.Result.Text)
        {
            case "say hello":
                MessageBox.Show("Hello Quanit!!");
                break;
            case "show my name":
                richTextBox1.Text += "\nQuanit";
                break;
        }
    }

    private void disableBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        recEngine.RecognizeAsyncStop();
        disableBtn.Enabled = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Add exception's full description to the question and the position where it is 
 being thrown

Comment: it is thrown on that line. recEngine.RecognizeAsync(RecognizeMode.Multiple);

Comment: You have recEngine.RecognizeAsync(RecognizeMode.Multiple);  in two places one in `Form1_Load` another in `enableBtn_Click`. It is not a good idea to start already started recognition, you probably want to keep just 1. Another issue is that you try to load grammar in async mode but do not wait for it to load. It is better to use simple `LoadGrammar`

Answer (score 0):

A couple ideas:

- You are calling LoadGrammarAsync. There's no guarantees the grammar is loaded before you call RecognizeAsync.
- You call RecognizeAsync twice.